# Is the floor considered a shelf?

Tags: word-usage

Googling "define shelf" says

> a flat length of wood or rigid material, attached to a wall or forming part of a piece of furniture, that provides a surface for the storage or display of objects.

Would the floor be considered a shelf?  The floor is a flat piece of rigid material attached to a wall that provides a surface for the storage AND display of objects.

What say you?

Comment: If I were a giant, then perhaps I could use a multistoreyed building as my personal shelf.

Comment: The definition is inadequate. [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shelf) is more rigorous: 'a thin flat plank of wood, metal, etc, fixed horizontally against a wall, etc, for the purpose of supporting objects'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as lacking research because a reasonable check on other dictionaries has not been done.

Comment: FWIW the floor *can* be a sort of shelf, colloquially... or at least in my family. We call the floor the 'dog shelf' or 'cat shelf' when remonstrating with members of those species about their current location on 'people shelves', aka chairs and couches. :)

Comment: If there is a shelving unit standing on the floor, and the bottom tier of the unit is such that if you insert an object at that level then it will be on the floor, vs on some piece of the shelving unit, then that portion of the floor would be considered to be the "bottom shelf".  This the only situation where the floor would be considered to be a "shelf", in US English common usage.

Comment: @HotLicks: I think even in that case, I would refer to objects on the floor as being "in the space beneath the bottom shelf" or "under the bottom shelf".

Comment: @sumelic - Yeah, it would tend to depend on the details of appearance of the shelving unit.

Comment: The floor is not attached to a wall; the walls are attached to the floor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions of *floor* and *shelf* in the Oxford English Dictionary make it clear that a floor is not a shelf.

**floor**, [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/71822?rskey=14iwon&result=1#eid)

> I. In a house or other structure.
>    1. a. The layer of boards, brick, stone, etc. in an apartment, on which people tread; the under surface of the interior of a room.....
>
> 2... a. The framework or structure of joists, etc. supporting the flooring of a room....
>       b. Applied to the ceiling of a room, in its relation to the apartment above

The OED says nothing about a floor being attached to a wall.

**shelf**, [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/177862?rskey=fCV6uA&result=1#eid)

I. 1. a. A slab of wood (or other material) fixed in a horizontal position to a wall, or in a frame, to hold books, vessels, ornaments, etc.; one of the transverse boards in a bookcase, cabinet, or the like.

**wall**, [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/225282?rskey=Qj2Fts&result=1#eid)

> 4..... (a) Each of the sides and vertical divisions of a building

The OED is having one of its free access periods as I write. If, however, these definitions can be accessed only by subscribers when you read this, I assure you that I read all the multiple definitions of shelf and floor in the OED thoroughly, and there is no loophole by which a shelf could become a floor in the OED definitions.

I hope a builder will weigh in on how walls and floors are attached to the load bearing elements of different kinds of structures to resolve any lingering confusion. I am not competent to do that.

As for the attachment issue, see the useful comment of @Jim:

> It’s the non-specificity of “attached to a wall” that is causing your
>   confusion. The way in which a real shelf is attached to a wall is not
>   the way in which a floor is attached to a wall.

Answer (score 1):

Oxford Dictionaries defines *floor* as follows:

> [*floor*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/floor): the lower surface of a room, on which one may walk

While *floor* may not be inconsistent with your definition of *shelf*, it must also meet the definition of *floor*, so no, a *floor* should not be considered a *shelf*.

Comment: True, *a floor* is not *a shelf* - but the "logic" you use to arrive at this conclusion makes no sense.

Comment: @michael.hor257k why do you think it's not a shelf?

Comment: @JohnCarpenter Because it is not. Language is not geometry, it does not obey dictionary definitions. And besides, a floor does **not**  "*provide a surface for the storage or display of objects*". Some floors (e.g. in a warehouse) *may* be used for storage and some floors (e.g. in a museum) *may* be used for display - but that is incidental to their purpose which is the purpose of *all* floors: to be walked on. And no, *stairs* are not *floors*.

Comment: Thanks for your perspective and thoughtful answer, however "Because it's not" is not a very satisfying answer imo

Comment: It’s the non-specificity of “attached to a wall” that is causing your confusion. The way in which a real shelf is attached to a wall is not the way in which a floor is attached to a wall.

Comment: @Jim Would it make any difference if the two methods of attachment were identical?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - it’s the non-specificity of my comment that is causing your confusion.  :-) Floors and shelves differ in attachment method, purpose, extent of coverage, etc.  I’m going to go out on a limb and say that shelves always are above floor level. even if that means just the thickness of the bottom shelf board.  I’m sure someone can contrive a situation that counters this, but it’d be the exception not the rule.

Comment: @Jim If there's any confusion, I may have caused it by not making it clear that my question was a rhetorical one.

Comment: 'The definition of _shelf_'? What about the better ones?